# Widget codes works intermittently

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-2.18, expression, fields-attributes

I have a QGIS program that is hosted on a SharePoint server that is used by multiple users. I have entered a rule for a point layer that when new features are created default values are added under certain fields. One such is generating the PARCEL_ID of the Field Parcel that the point feature is located in.
To generate this I have set the default value in the fields widget properties to:

`if (geomwithin('Field Parcels' , 'PARCEL_ID') is not NULL,geomwithin( 'Field Parcels' , 'PARCEL_ID'),geomintersects('Field Parcels' , 'PARCEL_ID'))`

This works for me normally, but for other users and if I use it on a remote assess computer it produces

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting COMMA or ')'

All users are using QGIS 2.18.20

Whats going on?

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but normally it would be `if(` not `if (` -- no space between if and the left parenthesis.

Comment: @csk Thanks for your help. I have tried adjusting spaces and using proper formatting but to no avail. From my very limited understanding, spaces don't matter in expression dialog.

Comment: The `geomwithin()` and `geomintersects()` functions are enabled by the refFunctions plugin. Do all your users have the current version of this plugin installed?

Comment: @csk You're a genius and I'm a fool. Thank you so much, that has sorted it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Once you've had a plugin installed for a while it's easy to forget that it's not a core feature. Case in point, it wasn't until I tried to re-create your issue that I remembered those functions aren't core features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geomwithin()` and `geomintersects()` functions are enabled by the **refFunctions plugin**. All users must have the *current* version of this plugin installed and enabled. 
[image]